# how to split String with a "pattern" from list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I've got a small problem with finding part of string in a list with python.

I load the string from a file and the value is one of the following: `(none, 1 from list, 2 from list, 3 from list or more...)`

I need to perform different actions depending on whether the String equals `""`, the String equals `1 element from list`, or if the String is for 2 or more elements. For Example:

```
List = [ 'Aaron', 'Albert', 'Arcady', 'Leo', 'John' ... ]
String = ""             #this is just example
String = "Aaron"        #this is just example
String = "AaronAlbert"  #this is just example 
String = "LeoJohnAaron" #this is just example
```

I created something like this:

```
if String == "":          #this works well on Strings with 0 values
    print "something"
elif String in List:      #this works well on Strings with 1 value
    print "something else"
elif ...                  #dont know what now
```

The best way would be to split this String with a pattern from a list. I was trying:

```
String.Find(x) #failed.
```

I tried to find similar posts but couldn't.

Comment: What kind of actions are you doing? I mean: if the text is `LeoJohnAaron` what should happen? Is there some connection between what happens to  `LeoJohn` and `LeoJohnAaron` or will the code do completely different things?

Comment: if text is LeoJohnAaron it should 
for example do 2 actions:
from another String substract lenght of this String
and print those names in separated lines

But its just an example. :)

Comment: And what happens with  `LeoJohnLeoLeo`? do repetition count? Does order matter? The general approach would be to use regexes, for example `re.findall('({})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, names))), text)` and loop over the matches, but depending on a number of factors I've pointed out simpler solution might be better.

Comment: There wont be a repetitions like LeoLeo :)
Order matters. If its LeoJohn I need to print Leo first and then John. And after printing I need to know that Leo was with John.
 I'm kinda new in python but it seems that RegEx is one or maybe the most important thing in it. Im gona study it tomorrow. Right now its time for sleep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if String == "":          #this works well on Strings with 0 values
    print "something"
elif String in List:      #this works well on Strings with 1 value
    print "something else"
elif len([1 for x in List if x in String]) == 2
    ...
```

This is called a list comprehension, it will go through the list and find all of the list elements that have a substring in common with the string at hand, then return the length of that.

Note that there may be some issues if you have a name like "Ann" and "Anna", the name "Anna" in the string will get counted twice. If you need a solution that accounts for that, I would suggest splitting on capital letters to explicitly separate the list into separate names by splitting on capital letters (If you want I can update this solution to show how to do that with regex)

Comment: Thanks, it works good, and I've got no repetitions in the code :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was my first question so u need to forgive me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward approach would be to loop over the list of names and for each of them check if its in your string.

```
for name in List:
   if name in String:
      print("do something here")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to find whether some string contains any members of the given list.

Iterate over the list and check whether the string contains the current item:

```
for data in List:
    if data in String:
        print("Found it!")
```